# Is it walking “in” or “on” the dunes?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm trying to do a translation and can't find any example that solves the question; is it walking *in* or *on* the dunes?

'Dunes' to the Dutch refers to an area which contains some sandy hills near the sea. The footpath is usually at a lower level, so we'd say 'in' the dunes for walking in the area, instead of 'on' as in on top of a sandy hill.

Comment: Where did you look for examples? The internet seems full of them. You walk _in_ the dunes, just like you walk _in_ the mountains.

Comment: It became a question when a Brittish relative told me it should be on the dunes, after that internet wasn't conclusive to me. Thanks anyway

Comment: When I saw your question title, my first thought was “on”, but, based on the second paragraph of your question, I suggest that you consider “through”.

Comment: This question asks for opinions.

Comment: You could alternatively say "roam the dunes" - so you do not need to care about "in" or "on"

Comment: You could also say _walk the dunes_ without a preposition and with the same verb. (I'm not sure this answers the question, though, and would be better as a comment; you'll soon be able to comment with a few points - a few good answers or a few good questions quickly gets you there.)

Comment: You could also walk *among* the dunes or *through* the dunes or *along* the dunes or *around* the dunes or any number of things.

Answer (score 9):

Both *in the dunes* and *on the dunes* are acceptable.

Another option, possibly better:

> Walking among the dunes

Comment: I definitely like *among*.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+dunes%2C+on+the+dunes%2C+among+the+dunes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camong%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0) for in/on/among the dunes.

Comment: @NigelJ it gets messier when you [include the verb](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=walk+in+the+dunes%2Cwalk+on+the+dunes%2Cwalk+among+the+dunes%2Cwalking+in+the+dunes%2Cwalking+on+the+dunes%2Cwalking+among+the+dunes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwalk%20in%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalk%20on%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalk%20among%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalking%20in%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalking%20on%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalking%20among%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @1006a Tate Modern will accept it, though.

Comment: _Among_ sounds very odd to me. It implies that the dunes are also walking, and while there is such a thing as a [wandering dune](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wandering%20dune), I don’t think that quite qualifies.

Answer (score 8):

To me, "in" means you're walking amongst and between the dunes, and "on" means actually climbing up and down the piles of sand. If there's a formal footpath designed to avoid most of the up-and-down, I'd probably go with "in" (or "among" as suggested by [Zanna's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/443755/177853)). If you want to emphasize the climbing aspect (or maybe damage done to vegetation by straying from designated paths or boardwalks), use "on".

Per [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=walking%20in%20the%20dunes%2Cwalking%20on%20the%20dunes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwalking%20in%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalking%20on%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwalking%20in%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalking%20on%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0), both version see some usage in print with "on" being somewhat more common in recent years, but the n is so low that I'm not sure that's a true trend (and the [data from 2000-2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=walking%20in%20the%20dunes%2Cwalking%20on%20the%20dunes&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwalking%20in%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalking%20on%20the%20dunes%3B%2Cc0) show "in" as more common). Disaggregating the data and looking at actual examples suggests some evidence for the distinction as I understand it (though I don't think it's a hard-and-fast rule by any means):

> **Walking in the dunes** is discouraged because paths created by walking can widen into large openings between dunes.
>   —[Scott Williams, *Corpus Christi*, 2009](https://books.google.com/books?id=wnd-BRGQFqcC&lpg=PT149&dq=%22walking%20in%20the%20dunes%22&pg=PT149#v=onepage&q=%22walking%20in%20the%20dunes%22&f=false)
>
> " . . . We will **walk in the dunes**, play some games and I will read you a book." . . . The bikes were parked and they started to walk in search of a cozy dip in the dunes that would give some protection from the wind. They soon found the most marvelous spot made just for them. It was a bit grassy as well as sandy right against a hillside—a little dell—large enough for the family.
>   —[Johanna Van Belle-Praamsma, *Coram Deo*, 2009](https://books.google.com/books?id=LsM-_6s1yrgC&lpg=PA120&dq=%22walk%20in%20the%20dunes%22&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q=%22walk%20in%20the%20dunes%22&f=false)
>
> They decide to go for a **walk in the dunes**, with Bernie, too, of course. Amelie learns that dunes are hills of sand, covered in grass and bushes. There are paths leading through them.
>   —[Eva Markert, *Amelie Travels to the Seaside, Stories for Little Ones*, 2017](https://books.google.com/books?id=72QqDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT24&dq=%22walk%20in%20the%20dunes%22&pg=PT24#v=onepage&q=%22walk%20in%20the%20dunes%22&f=false)
>
> With no experience of the coast, I thought it would be possible to **walk on the dunes, looking down on the sea** and whatever lay behind that tantalizing tangle of wire.
>   —[John Hillaby, *A Walk Through Europe*, 1977](https://books.google.com/books?id=JK0rAAAAMAAJ&q=%22walk%20on%20the%20dunes%22&dq=%22walk%20on%20the%20dunes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicq4Tg6traAhXhzIMKHQ4KAnoQ6AEIPjAE) (snippet view)
>
> During the day, Mark would often watch the tourists (whom the natives called "comers" and "goers") climbing the dunes. Some even walked up during the searing heat of the afternoon. Gramps said, "Anyone **walking on the dunes** in the blazing noonday sun is crazy. Between the burning sands and the broiling sun, you might as well be turning on a rotisserie."
>   —[Anne Turner Coppola, *Ghost Dunes*, 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=n3g3BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA30&dq=%22walking%20on%20the%20dunes%22&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=%22walking%20on%20the%20dunes%22&f=false)

Comment: +1 the examples of contemporary usage are useful. Also, one can certainly go walking in the dunes as one can go walking in the mountains. Here, dunes and mountains specificy the general place where the walking took place, not that one is walking "inside" the mountains or inside the dunes. And walking on the dunes is a definite doable for many for whom walking "on the mountains" is not conceiveable.

Answer (score 0):

There is another caveat to your question it seems.  To walk in the dunes would imply that the dunes are a location to visit, as you would be in the location where there are sand dunes and walking around.  To walk on the dunes implies that there is some geometry or feature that is being walked on.  In this context the word dunes is used interchangeably as a location to visit and an object or objects to be walked on the surface of.  The word is used to describe a place and objects in that same place.  You could make it clear which of the two meanings you want to use ahead of time.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to pick the “correct” preposition in English is really frustrating for those learning the language. While it is easy to see that “Worms live under the ground” is correct while “Worms live above the ground” is incorrect, it is not so clear with the above “dunes” example. There are many examples of multiple prepositions being acceptable (correct) for some phrase and many examples where the acceptable (correct) preposition depends on the version of English being spoken as in “in back of the car” (US English) and “behind the car” (British English). Native speakers will generally be able to give good reasons why the prepositions that they use are correct while others are incorrect. So which preposition is correct?  Let me answer it this way: if you were going to live in England, it would be preferable to learn English from a native UK English speaker rather than an American.  Similarly, the “correct” dune preposition depends on where you are and with whom you are speaking. Even so, a native English speaker (Australian, British, ...., Zimbabwean) will have no trouble understanding you.  Sorry about the long answer but this is one of those situations where trying to find the correct answer when there in no single correct answer is counterproductive.

Comment: I think many prepositions are by convention, that is, certain words are used with certain prepositions. For example: under the table, but below average. Below and under have similar meanings but they aren't interchangeable in this case. Also, I don't think there are good reasons in my examples, they are just 'by convention'.

Comment: whilst writing what you did, you didn't consider it worthwhile to write what you would say? and what dialect that represents?

Comment: I’m an Australian English speaker and, for what it’s worth, I’d normally go for a walk on the dunes.

Answer (score -2):

both correct for sure.depending on the situation,in the case you mean it was walking for fun or leisure so you describe the totality of circumstances,and choose to use "in".But on the other hand,talking about the details of the route it was passing in it's way,"on"will fit best.